# PHP Include Issues

Tags: php, html

I have a folder on my server named "layout", it contains two documents: top.html and bottom.html. I'm trying to come up with a PHP include script so that I can put it on the top and bottom of any page and have one single place to edit my layout. Things I've already tried:

**Code:**

```
<?php include '/layout/bottom/html' ?>
<?php include './layout/bottom/html' ?>
<?php include '../layout/bottom/html' ?>
<?php include '.../layout/bottom/html' ?>
<?php $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; $path .= "/layout/top.html"; include($path); ?>
```

**Error:**

> No such file or directory in C:---serverpath---\www\index.php on line 25

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: maybe just `layout/page.html`?

Comment: Please take the time and write at least a question into your question. We also love error messages.

Comment: I apologize, I guess it defeats the purpose to not ask a question lol. My question is, is there any way to make an include script that would work no matter the location of the files?

Comment: Just an FYI, you can remove all the opening and closing tags on each line. Since you have no HTML within your file, you need only one open PHP statement at the beginning of the file and one closing PHP statement at the end of your file.

Comment: The error messages I'm getting are baisicly saying it's only looking in it's own directory ie: No such file or directory in C:\---serverpath---\www\index.php on line 25

Comment: The top.html and bottom.html both contain html files, plus the files themselves will contain html. When echo'd by php, it will be almost entirely html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP includes are relative from the file you're including *from*.

So if you load `folder/script.php`

And in `script.php` you do:

```
include "layout/top.html";
```

It will look for: `folder/layout/top.html`

If instead you include your files like this:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . "/../layout/top.html";
```

It will look for: `folder/../layout/top.html` which resolves to: `layout/top.html`

If you then having another script: `folder/folder2/script2.php`, include like:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../layout/top.html";
```

---

As of PHP5.3 you **should** use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: Any reason why `dirname(__FILE__)` and not `__DIR__`?

Comment: +1, Ah, I always assume people are using the latest versions, your answer states 5.4, but according to [the manual](http://uk1.php.net/constants.predefined) - it was added in 5.3. (Just so you can edit your answer).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I guess one of my servers is still running PHP5.2 (I actually ran into this issue today).